# Is it acceptable to use 1uF decoupler on a 7805?

Tags: arduino, decoupling-capacitor, linear-regulator

I am feeding an arduino, presently through its Vin pin, with a 0.9V drop on its onboard regulatorZ I'd of course like to feed it via its 5V pin, which has a strict upper limit of 5.5V. I don't have any 7806/7808s, and already soldered the 7805 in place. I also have no 0.1uF caps, my nearest value is 1uF. The 7805 briefly spikes to 6-7V when powered up. I need to absorb that spike - can I get by with a 1uF cap on the output?

I am sorry for this trivial post, but I would be very sad if my arduinos died. I have already ordered 7808s and more suitable caps.

Comment: I'd be totally concerned about the spike on the 7805 output - don't use a band-aid - get to the root of the problem here.

Comment: Where did you get that the output spikes to 7V? I can't remember having seen that ever.

Comment: @Andyaka I am totally concerned. I power the 7805s from a 12V switching power supply, and because the board's space is a bit tight, I left out input and output caps.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Tested it when powering up the circuit. Have used 3 different DMMs. It is momentary.

Comment: @user2497: It can't be that "momentary" when you are able to read it with a dmm. Can you tell more about how you did measure it and with what dmm? You should better measure it with a scope, I can imagine the inductance of the leads distort the measurements. But if you are only concerned about what you measured, slap a 1µF on there and measure again.

Comment: @PlasmaHH The multimeters sample from 3 to 5 times per second. I just popped the power on and off with a dummy load attached to the 7805. Max/min.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Why would they distort the readings by +2V every time?

Comment: An input capacitor is just as necessary (some might say it is more important) as an output capacitor, especially if your 12V source is coming over a decent length of wires.

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes, I agree. Fortunately waiting for excellent answers here inspired me to dig through my drawers, and I now have the caps I need. The spike seems to be max 5.4V on my fastest sampling DMM, so I'll risk it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH You made me recheck my readings, thanks. Have no scope :/ Anyway, that makes you the answerer. Post comment as answer.

Comment: @user2497: How hard is your power source switching on, and is it maybe overshooting too at that point? The regulator can only react so fast to a change in the input voltage and regulate it down. In that case it might be more useful to use a regulator with a shutdown/enable pin. Or you might want to check if for the short spike you want a zener protection.

Comment: @PlasmaHH It is switching on as most modern PC power supplies switch on. It is in standby until I flip a switch. After a few readings, its 12V signal seems to hit 13.2V when coming out of standby.

Comment: @user2497 providing a formal answer when there is a glaring problem with the spike is far less important than getting you to solve the spike issue. If you want to provide an answer saying you found some capacitors as a means of burying your head in the ground and getting closure then that is up to you.

Comment: @Andyaka Get closure? Do not watch psychological material on TV.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes, that is an excellent idea. In any case I cannot know the exact voltage when I power up the 7805, and arduinos die above 5.5, however brief. Thanks, I will get access to a scope.

Comment: Well, don't think that masking a significant bleed with a band aid isn't going to pose you problems. Are you going to recommend that I don't watch any form of medical prog now?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes. Don't watch TV again.

Comment: @user2497: It seems we have generally here a mismatch in the level of detail. By "how hard" it is generally meant on how fast the input voltage rises, or similar (depending on what the input signal really is). The regulator can only keep up with this change up to a certain speed, especially when it overshoots, even briefly. This is happening in so short timeframes that to see what is going on a DMM usually is too slow. But this also means that you can hide such issues by filtering with a cap.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Post the comment about reaction time of regulator as an answer. Thanks again ;)

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes, I will add the caps now - and a switch for good measure. Your insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, we want the output of a 7805 to be 5V, no matter what. The regulator surely does its best, but there are two things that it needs to react to:

- output current demand
- input voltage

Ignoring the output for now, when you switch on the input, the voltage rises with a certain speed, and if that speed is faster than the internals of the 7805 are designed to react to, it will lag in regulating the voltage down, leading to higher output voltage than desired.

Usually it should not happen to really go that far beyond the 5V, but it is not totally inconceivable.

You can hide that voltage spike by adding more output capacitance, but how much is mostly a thing of experimentation. You should also add some good input capacitance to slow down the rise of the input voltage to give the regulator more time to react.

If you worry so much about the output voltage not going out of spec, there are some things you may want to consider:

- protect it with a zener
- use some kind of switch to only switch on when the voltage is stable
- use a better regulator, possibly one with a shutdown/enable pin that you set up with an RC to go on when the input voltage is a bit more stable.

Comment: I used 0.47uF on input, 0.33uF on output, and now observe no spike when I power up the 7805. Very good 

Answer (score 1):

> can I get by with a 1uF cap on the output?

you have to find out the datasheet for your specific 7805 and see what requirements it has. while most of them are fairly "typical", there are differences and no one is more authoritative on your question than the datasheet for your device.

Comment: The datasheet uses a 330nF on input and 100nF on output. I raised these values as per @PlasmaHH's answer, and it seems to have resolved the issue. It is no doubt my power supply that is the culprit, though.

Comment: It is generally true that you should respect those valued specified in the datasheet, especially if you are dealing with ldos as larger capacitance tend to cause oscillation. That's notbtobsay that you would get away with larger capacitance just that your margin for error is smaller. So always read the datasheet. People who gave you advice without knowing your chip and reading its datasheet are really BSing you.

Comment: Right, but I have read the datasheet, and have no reason to think that @PlasmaHH is 'bullshitting' me. I did not use a 470uF cap, after all, it was a modest increase of the values.